# Cannot access property of generic list item

Tags: c#, .net

Hello I am getting an error accessing a propery of a generic list that have been passed a parameter to a function. My code is as follows:

**Program**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var stregsystem = new Stregsystem();
}
```

**class User**

```
public int UserID = 10;
```

**class Stregsystem**

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

public Stregsystem() {
    users.Add(new User());
    users.Add(new User());
    users.Add(new User());

    CSV.Write<User>(users);
}
```

**class CSV**

```
public static void Write<T>(List<T> list) {
    Console.WriteLine(list.Count());

    Console.WriteLine(list[0].UserID);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error  1   'T' does not contain a definition for 'UserID' and no extension >method 'UserID' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you >missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   >D:\Development\OOP\CSV.cs  14  39  OOP

I assume the error is lying in the Write function but I have no clue what the issue is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Write` is a generic method.  Written as is, you can call it with any type `T`.  And you certainly can't assume any type has the property `UserId`.  Do this instead:

```
public static void Write(List<User> list) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
    Console.WriteLine(list[0].UserID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error since you put your method as generic

```
public static void Write(List<User> list) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
    Console.WriteLine(list[0].UserID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the properties of T we need to use Reflection as we'd not know the details about T (i.e.  List)

```
 public void WriteData<T>(ref ExcelWorksheet workSheet,List<T> list)
    {

        workSheet.TabColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        workSheet.DefaultRowHeight = 12;
        //Header of table  
        //  
        workSheet.Row(1).Height = 20;
        workSheet.Row(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        workSheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
        ...
        ...
        ...


        foreach(T item in list)
        {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperties();

            int cellIndex = 1;
            workSheet.Column(cellIndex).AutoFit();
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info in propertyInfo)
            {
                object value = info.GetValue(item, null);
                workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, cellIndex++].Value = value;
            }

            recordIndex++;
        }
    }
```